# I am learning calculus and minima maxima . This is the sum where I I stuck on have no idea

Tags: derivatives

A school charges Rs 50 per student if not more than 300 students enroll. The charges decrease by 10 paise for each student in excess of 300. How many students should be enrolled so as to have maximum revenue

Comment: The other problem you posted was closed because you showed no work of your own.  The same thing will happen to this one unless you give some context.  How far can you get with this?  Can you set up a formula for the quantity you are trying to maximize?  How do you go about finding the maximum of a function?  Where do you get stuck?  Be sure to put these details in the body of your question, **not** in a comment.

Comment: Important for those who do not know, that the indian rupee is subdivided into 100 paise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a derivative......the maximum revenue occurs when $n > 300$. The equation for revenue is

$R = 50n - 0.1(n - 300)n$...... which simplifies to:

$R = -0.1n^2 + 80n$

Max $R$ occurs where $R' = 0$

$R' = -0.2n + 80 = 0$

$n = \frac{80}{0.2} = 400$

Max $R = -0.1(400)^2 + 80(400) = 16 000$ rupees.

Answer (score 0):

There are 100 "paise" in one "rupee" so 10 paise is 0.1 rupee. If the number of students, x, is larger than 300, the revenue per student is 50- 0.1(x- 300)= 80- 0.1x.  The total revenue, then, is $x(80- 0.1x)= 80x- 0.1x^2$.  Complete the square: $80x- 0.1x^2= -0.1(x^2- 800x+ 160000- 160000)= -0.1(x- 400)^2+ 16000$.  Since that is 16000 **minus** something, it will be maximum when that "something" is 0- when x= 400.